# set up 301 redirect from subdirectory to specific html file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm running apache on ubuntu 14.04 and trying to set up 301 redirects. Redirection is working, but not as expected. Here's what I have:

```
#REDIRECTS
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


# REMOVES INDEX.PHP
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# REDIRECT SPECIFIC PAGES
Redirect 301 /main http://mikeheavers.com
Redirect 301 /main/ http://mikeheavers.com
Redirect 301 /main/code http://mikeheavers.com/tutorials.html
Redirect 301 /main/code/ http://mikeheavers.com/tutorials.html
```

The first two `redirect 301`s work, but the rest, such as `/main/code`, try to redirect to http://mikeheavers.com/code and note http://mikeheavers.com/tutorials.html. What am I doing wrong?

---

update: note that I need to be able to redirect urls both containing and not containing the trailing slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix `mod_rewrite` rules with `mod_alias` that has `Redirect` directive. Use this:

```
#REDIRECTS
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# REDIRECT SPECIFIC PAGES
RewriteRule ^main/?$ http://mikeheavers.com [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^main/code/?$ http://mikeheavers.com/tutorials.html [L,NC,R=301]

# REMOVES INDEX.PHP
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thanks - how do I handle the situation where I want to be able to redirect the url with or without the trailing slash though? I believe your example only allows for the trailing slash to be included.